# Limit of an n-ary product

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, notation, products

Since a definite integral is defined as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i^*)\,\Delta x = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$$
and the integral is much easier to calcluate than a sum, if we change the sum to a product:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=0}^n f(x_i^*)\,\Delta x = \text{?}$$
What would be the simpler form of that expression, which, like an integral, would be easier to calculate, if it exists?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137399/is-there-a-continuous-product?rq=1 is related and I believe will place your question in the right context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a [product integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral), which can be written as:

$$\prod_a^b{f(x)^{dx}}$$