# Addition is to Integration as Multiplication is to ______

Tags: calculus, analysis

Addition is to Integration as Multiplication is to ______ ? Everyone knows that definite integration  is "a way to sum continuum-many terms" in a rough sense. Can we "multiply continuum-many factors"  in a similar sense?

Comment: How about $e^{\int f}$?

Comment: @ajotatxe Its True! But i don't think OP was expecting this :)

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Is there a “continuous product”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137399/)

Answer (score 46):

If $f\colon [a,b] \to (0,\infty)$, then the closest analogue to a multiplicative integral of $f$ is
$$
{\prod}_a^b \,f(x)^{dx} \;\underset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\; \exp\left(\int_a^b \ln f(x)\,dx\right).
$$
This has the following properties:

1. If $a<r<b$, then $\displaystyle{\prod}_a^b\,f(x)^{dx} = \left({\prod}_a^r\,f(x)^{dx}\right)\left({\prod}_r^b\,f(x)^{dx}\right)$.
2. If $f(x)$ is a constant funtion $C$, then $\displaystyle{\prod}_a^b\,f(x)^{dx} = C^{b-a}$.
3. $\displaystyle{\prod}_a^a \,f(x)^{dx} = 1$ for any function $f$.
4. $\displaystyle {\prod}_a^b\,\bigl(f(x)g(x)\bigr)^{dx} \;=\; \left({\prod}_a^b\,f(x)^{dx}\right)\left({\prod}_a^b\,g(x)^{dx}\right)$
5. $\displaystyle\left({\prod}_a^b \,f(x)^{dx}\right)^k \;=\; {\prod}_a^b \,\bigl(f(x)^k\bigr)^{dx}$ for any constant $k$.
6. The ([Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)) geometric mean of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ is $\displaystyle\left({\prod}_a^b \,f(x)^{dx}\right)^{1/(b-a)}$.
7. If $f$ is continuous, then $\displaystyle{\prod}_a^b \,f(x)^{dx}$ is the limit of a "Riemann product":
   $$
   \displaystyle{\prod}_a^b \,f(x)^{dx} \;=\; \lim_{\max \Delta x_i\to 0}\, \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i^*)^{\Delta x_i}.
   $$
8. If $\displaystyle F(t) = {\prod}_a^t f(x)^{dx}$, then $e^{F'(t)/F(t)} = f(t)$.  Similarly, for any $C^1$ function $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, we have 
   $$
   {\prod}_a^b \bigl(e^{f'(x)/f(x)}\bigr)^{dx} = \frac{f(b)}{f(a)}
   $$

Comment: did you just come up with this? I haven't seen this before, does it have a name or are you still thinking about it :)?

Comment: @user190080 I've known about it for years, but I'm not sure whether I figured it out on my own or heard about it from somebody.  There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) for it under the name "product integral".

Comment: ah, nice, thanks for the reference!

Comment: Maybe the following explanation is also helpful: Basically, $\exp$ transforms addition into multiplication (i.e. $\exp : (\Bbb{R}, +) \to ( (0,\infty), \cdot)$ is an isomorphism). In particular, we have $x \cdot y = \exp(\ln x + \ln y)$. Now, we basically just replace addition on the right hand side by integration (after all, we are asking "addition is to integration as multiplication is to ...") and obtain the "product integral".

Answer (score 11):

Convolution is analogous to multiplication.

Comment: don't know why, but that would be my answer too :)

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, I think. Convolution definitely captures the mathematical structure of multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

[Product Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral). Math With Bad Drawings has an [article](http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2014/01/29/the-mathematician-and-the-unfinished-coffee/) that mentions it.

I think the one presented by Jim Belk is only Type I. Here is [Type II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_II).